# Windows ML - ONNX - Exception from HRESULT: 0x88900105

Tags: uwp, azure-cognitive-services, onnx

I'm reading this article : [Add a bit of machine learning to your Windows application thanks to WinML](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/appconsult/2018/05/23/add-a-bit-of-machine-learning-to-your-windows-application-thanks-to-winml/) and reproduced the sample application. It currently works.

On Azure Custom Vision portal, i built my own vision model and exported it in ONNX 1.0 for Windows 10 build 1803, but when i'm trying running the sample with my own model, i have the Following exception :

Exception from HRESULT: 0x88900105

When the program go on this line :

```
LearningModelEvaluationResultPreview evalResult = await learningModel.EvaluateAsync(binding, string.Empty);
```

It is a little tricky to know where it comes from because the exception is not very explicit.

I would like to know if you have encountered the same problem or have an idea where it might come from.

Edit: steps for reproduce the problem.

---

Download my model here : https://1drv.ms/u/s!AqIRdnJsFoE6iu4N0vI89qa-C76iZg

Clone the repository from GitHub : https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-AppConsult-Samples-UWP

Run the sample with a plane picture, the sample works.

Now In the solution, replace the existing (and working) PlanesModel.onnx by mine.

We get the exception.

Here all my project's configuration:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Could you share a mini sample ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution for this problem thanks to Azure Custom Vision support, i share the solution here:

> The blog post is not being maintained by Custom Vision service.  We
>   recommend following the sample in this link
>   https://github.com/Azure-Samples/cognitive-services-onnx-customvision-sample
>   if you are interested in using ONNX 1.0 model with Windows 10 1803.
>
> If you want to keep using the existing sample you provide. Can you
>   modify the autogenerated cs file.
>
> Add this line
>
> `learningModel.InferencingOptions.PreferredDeviceKind = LearningModelDeviceKindPreview.LearningDeviceGpu;`
>
> before assigning to onnxmodel.